# Is R2RML suitable for EAV tables?

Tags: rdf, entity-attribute-value, r2rml

Beginning to read about R2RML I wonder if this language would also be suitable for mapping database tables that follow the *entity-attribute-value* model to *RDF* and how a simple example would look like.

[A survey of RDB to RDF translation approaches and
tools](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/903568/filename/Michel_Montagnat_Faron_2013_-_A_survey_of_RDB_to_RDF_translation_approaches_and_tools.pdf) refers to a "1 table to n classes" feature as followed:

> Ability to use the values of a column as a categorization pattern: tuples of the table will be translated into instances of different ontological classes based on the value of this attribute. This feature can be seen as an extension of the "select conditions" feature as it results in not only filtering out rows, but the filter helps selecting rows to
>   be converted into instance of one class or another.

Comment: Would you not just use an RDF store for your EAV data. Would you still need your EAV tables?

Comment: @NatanCox Indeed, I'd consider that in a green-field project, but in my case the EAV tables are already existing and used on data entry side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple mapping could look like this:

```
[
  rr:logicalTable [ rr:tableName "eav_table" ] ;
  rr:subjectMap [ rr:template "http://example.com/ontology.rdf#Entity/{entity_column}/" ] ;
  rr:predicateObjectMap [
    rr:predicateMap [
      rr:template "http://example.com/ontology.rdf#{attribute_column}"
    ] ;
    rr:objectMap [
      rr:template "http://example.com/ontology.rdf#Value/{value_column}/"
    ]
  ]
] .
```

If a more sophisticated SQL statement is needed, one would use `rr:sqlQuery` instead of `rr:tableName`:

```
  rr:logicalTable [
    rr:sqlQuery "SELECT entity_column, attribute_column, value_column FROM eav_table;"
  ] ;
```

For the set of available attributes, the corresponding predicates may be further characterized by additional mappings.